# Intercept http response and alter it with PHP

Tags: php, apache, capture

there is a way to intercept an HTML DOM using an apache module and alter it with PHP?

The purpose is apply a set of PHP rules on all websites hosted on server (for example, replacing some strings).

### SOLVED

I will update later with the solution

Comment: What you need is a "proxy". If you search for a PHP proxy you'll find many scripts to build upon.

Comment: @tacone I never found a php based proxy that really worked without issues. I would not invest into that approach...

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the htaccess (possibly set-able server wide in apache conf) value:

`php_value auto_prepend_file`

I've used that before for handling any errors php throws, so with a little hacking you could have it prepend a script that buffers content and modifies it, I'm not sure how foolproof you can make it though.

Comment: I think that by this way I can inject code to PHP's only pages. I have to edit static pages too

Answer (score 0):

This certainly is possible, different approaches exist.

Here an example of what I do to add a js tracking snippet to pages: http://blog.christian-reiner.info/2013/01/23/piwik/ The basic steps I use in there are: server side inclides (SSI) and substitution of closing body tags in *all* delivered html pages by preceding it with a small javascript. That javascript is generated by means of php. So a small php script is called automatically by the apache http server right before sending any html page to a client to add this small script.

Other good starting point certainly is apaches `mod_ext_filter`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ext_filter.html

Comment: Did you? Can't see that in the question. But anyway, fine if I put you on the right track :-)